# ZF can be axiomatized with reflection, $\Delta_0$-specification, foundation, and extension?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, foundations

[This comment](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/feferman_set_theory.html#c030090) on the n-Category Café says that [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) can be axiomatized using [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle), [$\Delta_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy)-[specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification), [foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), and [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). Which form of reflection is needed, exactly? And is there a reference in the literature for this statement (preferably with page number)?

Comment: I guess it would be like: for every set $x$ and a first-order formula $\phi(x)$, there is $\alpha$ such that $x\in V_\alpha$ and $\phi(x)\leftrightarrow \phi(x)^{V_\alpha}$.